# how to $sort by field of subdocument belonging to an array?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql, aggregation-framework, mongodb-indexes

Schema:

```
{
  A: [
    { name: "string", age: "integer" },
    { name: "string", age: "integer" },
    { name: "string", age: "integer" },
    ...
  ]
}
```

compound index:

```
{
  "A.name": 1,
  "A.age": 1,
}
```

query

```
db.col.aggregate([
  { $match: { A: { $elemMatch: { name: "XYZ"  } } } },
  { $sort: { "A.age": 1 } }
  { $set: ... }
  ...
  { $limit: 10 }
])
```

The above query will sort the array based on all of the subdocuments of `A`.

How to get it to sort just based on the matching subdocuments? And then also to use the index?

Comment: Would you please shere what **output you needed** and **one example of document** ?
i am confused your array is a document or part of document as a subdocument

Comment: "The above query will sort the array based on all of the subdocuments of A." No it, does not! It will sort the documents, not the array. `{ $sort: { "A.age": 1 } }` will sort on the **first** element of `A`

Comment: Arrays are funny in mongodb, see the comparison/sort order: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/#arrays

Answer (score 0):

You can use **$sortArray** Aggregation Pipeline Operator

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
   // ... previous Aggregation Stages 
   { $project:
      {
          _id: 0,
          result:
            {
               $sortArray: { input: "$A", sortBy: { name: 1 ,age: 1} }
            }
      }
   }
] )
```